# cannot convert 'list*' to 'Node*' in assignment

Tags: c++, graph

I'm trying to construct an adjacency list. The code I wrote is as follows.

```
struct Node
{
    int dest;
    struct Node* next;  
};

struct list
{
    struct list *head;
};
```

The class is defined as:

```
class Graph
{
    private:
        int vertix;
        list *arr;
    public:
        Graph(int v)
        {
            vertix = v;
            arr = new list [vertix];
            for(int i=0;i<vertix;i++)
            {
                arr[i].head=NULL;
            }
        }

        Node* getNewNode(int destination)
        {
            Node* newNode = new Node;
            newNode->dest = destination;
            newNode->next = NULL;
            return newNode;
        }
```

The errors are in these functions:

```
        void addEdge(int src, int dest)
        {
            Node* newNode = getNewNode(dest);
            newNode->next = arr[src].head;
            arr[src].head = newNode;

            newNode = getNewNode(src);
            newNode->next = arr[dest].head;
            arr[dest].head = newNode;

        }
    void print()
    {
        cout<<"Adjacency list of vertix: "<<endl;
        for(int i = 0; i< vertix; i++)
        {
            Node *ptr = arr[i].head;
            cout<< i << "-->";
            while(ptr)
            {
                cout<< "-->"<<ptr->dest;
                ptr=ptr->next;
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }    

  };
```

The error messages I get are:
[Error] cannot convert 'list*' to 'Node*' in assignment
[Error] cannot convert 'list*' to 'Node*' in initialization

Comment: YOu do not need to implement a linked list on your own, you can also use std::list as well.

Comment: On which lines do you get these messages?

Comment: Looks like your `list` struct should have pointer to `Node`, not to `list`.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 "newNode->next = arr[src].head;" in addEdge function and "Node *ptr = arr[i].head;" in print function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is just a typo, but instead of

```
struct list
{
    struct list *head;
};
```

you should have

```
struct list
{
    Node *head;
};
```

since the head of a list is a node, not another list. This causes the error in this line:

```
Node *ptr = arr[i].head;
```

because you are trying to assign the head of the list (which in your current code is a `list*`) to a `Node*`

Comment: it is still giving me the exact same error in addEdge and print functions

Comment: @Saad, did you check the link in my previous comment? It is a link to ideone, and your code compiles just fine